# How to start an iOS app with a modal view controller already presented without the user being able to see the presenting view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, launch, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've tried many combinations of doing this from the app delegate, the presenting view controller's `viewDidLoad`, with and without delay, with and without animation.

But either the user can see the presenting view controller for a moment, or the modal doesn't get presented.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried code below with storyboard, app starts with modal view controller:

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalSegue" sender:self];

    return YES;
}
```

Segue configuration from start view controller to modal view controller:

[image]

Comment: The modal doesn't present for me here.  But maybe it is because I'm using storyboard?  How would I do it with storyboard?

Comment: **UPD**: Updated answer for storyboards

Comment: Tested this on iOS 7, iOS 6 simulators, and iOS 7 device.  Thanks!

Comment: I see now what I was missing from my previous attempts.  `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]`.  If I remove this line, it doesn't work.  Time to read... thanks again.

Comment: Reading the docs didn't help me understand why `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` is needed.  Why does it make a difference?

Comment: There is a warning when you try presenting modal view without this line - `Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0xa37d320> on <UIViewController: 0xa37d0a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. After you call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` `self.window.rootViewController.view` is added to the window hierarchy and modal vc is being presented without warnings.

Comment: This doesn't work. In iOS 9 with storyboards (segue kind: `Present modally`) the underlying view is still visible for a couple of tens of milliseconds even if the segue has `Animates` disabled.

Answer (score 1):

What if your inititalViewController had a picture of your launch image over it.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *launchImage;
```

Set the launch image before the view appears.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    self.launchImage.image = [self launchImage];
}
```

[Here's a link to get the launch image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298477/ios-uiimage-of-launch-image-for-current-device).

Then when you present the modal view controller, remove the launch image.

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
    [self.launchImage removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Comment: Clever answer :).  I didn't try it but sounds like a nice work around.